# Is there a way I can declare function in objects from other files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Objective**

The objective is to declare function inside a object from other files

**Failed attempt**

> Message is a class

**first file**

```
const {Message} = require(The class)
const secondFile = require('./secondFile.js')
 Message.prototype.logMessage = SecondFile.logMessage()
```

**second file**

```
module.exports = {
    logMessage:()=>{
        console.log('LOG')
    }
}
```

Minimum Reproducible example

classFile.js

```
class Example {
    constructor(param){

    }
    exampleFunction(){
        //do something
    }
}
module.exports = Example
new Example('example')
```

1st File

```
const classFile = require('./ClassFile')
const secondFile = require('./2.js')
classFile.prototype.exampleFunction2 = SecondFile.logMessage()
```

2nd File

```
module.exports = {
    exampleFunction2:()=>{
        console.log('LOG')
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question? What goes wrong? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `SecondFile.logMessage()`. That calls the function instead of assigning the function itself.